# Replace .gitignore file upon removal

Tags: git, command-line

I use a `results` directory for storing data generated by my code. This data I do not wish to keep in the repo, so I ignore all files with the extensions the data uses (.csv, .txt).

Unfortunately, git does not track empty directories. A solution, as presented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115983/how-can-i-add-an-empty-directory-to-a-git-repository), is to stick a `.gitignore` file in the directory. This works well. However....

I often want to clean out the directory to not confuse old results with new. Often, I will rename the old one and make a new one with the old name. (e.g., now I will have the directorys `results_old` and an empty `results`).

The problem is that now the .gitignore file is missing from the `results` directory and I need to manually add it back.

Is there any utility that can be used to 'replace' the .gitignore or enforce that it is 'recreated' in that directory?

Top level `.gitignore` contents:

```
*.csv
*.txt
*.text
__pycache__
```

Comment: Can you post your .gitignore file (the top one, don't put one in the results directory)?  Also, why are you tracking the results directory if it just contains data output that you want to ignore?

Comment: @SteveHarris Tracking the directory so that an error does not occur if the directory does not exist. The script could check for it, but I was wondering if there was another way.

Comment: I think the directory should be considered a runtime or build artifact and handle it that way.  Much easier to maintain, as you are seeing.

Answer (score 2):

Your setup should create the directory if not exists, perhaps during application initialization. That is easier than deleting and figuring out way of recreating it. You can still ignore the entire path by single line and don't have to think about the directory at all.